# Is puts reentrant?

Tags: c, signals, reentrancy

Is `int puts(const char*);` re-entrant? Can I safely put it into a signal handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_04) is a table with all functions considered safe for signal handling:

> "The following table defines a set of
>   functions that shall be either
>   reentrant or non-interruptible by
>   signals and shall be
>   async-signal-safe."

`puts` does not seem to be in that list, however per [this](http://fixunix.com/unix/493297-puts-reentrant.html), it is deemed reentrant, but not async-safe, perhaps why it is not in the above mentioned list.

Comment: Hmm, where is the difference between `puts` and `write`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: don't know for sure, but `puts()` is part of stdio, which in itself is not async-signal-safe. Possibly, but not limited to, features like output buffering.

Comment: @Christian Yeah you are right, I totally forgot that the whole stdio is working on top of `FILE` structures not file descriptors.

Comment: The issue is the memory buffering; `puts()` may buffer, which may require a new buffer to be allocated, which may require calling `sbrk()` or `mmap()` to allocate memory. Those two functions are not async-signal-safe. (The actual underlying `write()` to the stdout FD is fine though.)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, you can however use `write()`, which is async signal safe, to output messages from a signal handler:

```
#include <unistd.h>

const char* msg = "The message to print.";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
```

Comment: Is `strlen()` itself async signal safe?

Comment: I [think](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) it is. "The following table defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions." ... and later ... "strlen".

Comment: Thanks for the info!